# Реализация приложения без рамки на PyQt5

Tags: python, gui, pyqt5

Доброго времени суток!

Хочу реализовать приложение на PyQt5 , которое выделяет определенную область на экране. В варианте с рамкой приложения все работает хорошо . Но вот когда убираю рамку приложения (`Qt.FramelessWindowHint`) начинаются проблемы.

Приложение как-будто сворачивается и ничего не выполняется. Не могу понять, почему так происходит.

Код:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.begin = QPoint()
        self.end = QPoint()
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        col = QColor(0, 0, 0)
        col.setNamedColor('red')
        qp.setPen(col)
        qp.drawRect(QRect(self.begin, self.end))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.begin = event.pos()
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MyWidget()
    window.showFullScreen()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3):

Проблемы автора возникали у меня (`Win7`) с атрибутом `Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground`.

Немного код подправил:

- Закрытие виджета через <kbd>Esc</kbd> кнопку
- Рисование фона
- Другие небольшие изменения

По идеи, `Qt.FramelessWindowHint` не нужен, если вызывается `showFullScreen`, т.к. при показе во весь экран, рамка окна и так не рисуется

Код:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.begin = QPoint()
        self.end = QPoint()

        flags = self.windowFlags() | Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
        self.setWindowFlags(flags)

        self.showFullScreen()

    def keyReleaseEvent(self, event):
        # Закрытие на кнопку Escape
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.close()

        super().keyReleaseEvent(event)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)

        # Рисуем свой задний фон
        qp.save()
        qp.setBrush(Qt.white)
        qp.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        qp.drawRect(self.rect())
        qp.restore()

        col = QColor(0, 0, 0)
        col.setNamedColor('red')
        qp.setPen(col)
        qp.drawRect(QRect(self.begin, self.end))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.begin = event.pos()
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()

        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()

        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()

        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWidget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```